# EF core to support nvarchar

Tags: entity-framework, nvarchar

I have an existing EF code first project which has created the database with all nvarchar columns in the database. Now I am starting another project on the same database for statistical purpose. This new project however is using EF core as pointing to same database. When I tried to run the new project, it gives me following error.

"Data type 'VARCHAR' is not supported in this form. Either specify the length explicitly in the type name, for example as 'VARCHAR(16)', or remove the data type and use APIs such as HasMaxLength to allow EF choose the data type."

Now, as I already have production data in the database so I want to make minimum impact to the column types but still wan to use EC core in my new project. I have so many nvarchar columns so setting configuration on individual table is a hard job. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the 2.0 release of EntityFrameworkCore: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9188

Supposed to get fixed in 2.1 so you may want to wait until then.

Otherwise they suggest manually fixing it like this:

```
            entity.Property(e => e.Comments)
                .HasColumnName("Comments")
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(4000)"); // <- Add this
```

Comment: In db-first, it should do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using data annotation and it still works.
`[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]`

Comment: i thought net core didn't support DB first any more, and in my case, im using  code first

Comment: Never mind, now it works. But the scaffolding tools are buggy as hell.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm its been fixed on later version, not sure about 2.1 but it disappeared in 2.2 for sure.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13609